# Why there are cache and page_cache different folders in magento 2.x

Tags: magento2

I am new to magento 2.x and was wondering to see that Magento 2.x has 2 folders for cache:

- /var/cache folder
- /var/page_cache folder

My question is that why there are 2 different folders?

Also what are differences among `/var/view_preprocessed`, `/var/generation` and `/pub/static` folders?

Please can anyone explain the differences and use of above folders?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- `/var/cache`: Magento cache (config, blocks, etc...)
- `/var/page_cache`: Magento full page cache (aka FPC)
- `/var/generation` or `/generated`: Auto generated Magento code (Interceptors, etc...)
- `/var/view_preprocessed`: Static contents before processing (like CSS and processed LESS files)
- `/pub/static`: Public static files (like JS, CSS, HTML, etc...)